# I want to ignore a SPECIFIC file in .gitignore that starts with a dot (.)

Tags: git, gitignore

I searched unsuccesfully for this answer.  Given a file name ".foo", I want it to be ignored by Git.

```
# My git ignore 

# ignore .foo, I only want .bar
.foo
```

Git ignores me instead of the file. :)

Comment: That's the way you do it. Maybe you have included that file in previous commits and want to not include it anymore?

Answer (score -1):

use backSlash "/" end of file name and commit in git 
example :  .idea/
.vscode/

all file in directory .idea or .vscode ignore from git